# Insert a separator between a number with Regex

Tags: r, regex, regexp-replace

I have a 20 digits number. Something like: `000001001520081000000`.

But I have to turn this to `00000100-15.2008.1.00.0000`. After seven numbers, I have to insert a `-`. Then, after 2, I insert a dot. Then, again after four, one and two numbers.

I was trying find the number this way: `d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d` 
and then convert to `\d\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d.\d.\d\d\d\d.\d\d\d\d` , but it was not working.

Then, I really do not know how to do. I am using R and I tried with `grep` .

Answer (score 3):

`(\d{7})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d)(\d{2})(\d{4})`

By placing capture groups around each of your intervals, you can use `gsub` to insert values between the matches.

```r
gsub(
  "(\\d{7})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})(\\d)(\\d{2})(\\d{4})", 
  "\\1-\\2,\\3,\\4,\\5,\\6", 
  "000001001520081000000", 
  perl=TRUE
)
```

`[1] "0000010-01,5200,8,10,00000"`

Comment: The `print` call doesn’t actually do anything here, it’s redundant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I... did not know that. Editing answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp <- as.character("000001001520081000000")
tmp2 <- paste0(substr(tmp, 1, 8),
               "-",
               substr(tmp, 9, 10),
               ".",
               substr(tmp, 11, 14),
               ".",
               substr(tmp, 15, 15),
               ".",
               substr(tmp, 16, 17),
               ".",
               substr(tmp, 18, nchar(tmp)))
tmp2
```

Output:

[1] "00000100-15.2008.1.00.0000"